# How to configure Laravel 5.1 routing?

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I have installed a fresh laravel 5.1 via composer. The default predefined routing one looks like following.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

After installation and basic configuration following Laravel 5.1 its documentation, it works fine with this above routing. But when I changed it into:

```
Route::get('test', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});   

or 

Route::get('/test', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

and tried to access the same page via:

```
http://localhost/mylaravel/public/test
```

I've got the following error.

```
Not Found
The requested URL /mylaravel/public/test was not found on this server.
```

It seams like the routing does not work. I have enabled the `mod_rewrite` as follows.

```
a2enmod rewrite

service apache2 restart
```

I have tried three different `.htaccess` as follows.

```
# the defualt one
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# attempt two
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# attempt three
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It does not work at all. What did I forget to configure? How can I solve this routing issue?

Comment: Do you have a local server running?

Comment: Yes, when I access the page via http://localhost/mylaravel/public/ I could see the welcome page.

Comment: Ok, just checking. Where is your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: try this `Route::get('/test', 'welcome');`

Comment: @Stuart Wagner: my .htaccess lives in the public directory as by default.

Comment: @OConnor Alright. Try to add something like `RewriteBase /mylaravel/public/` to the `.htaccess`.

Comment: @Mubin Knalid: I have tries as you said. But it does not work. Note that there is not WelcomeController since it is a fresh installation.

Comment: there should be `WelcomeController` in your `app->http->Controller`'s directory.
can you try to access it `index`? 
`localhost/your_app/index.php/test`
OR
`localhost/your_app/index.php/?test`
as per doc(http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#pretty-urls), I'm assuming you've `Rewrite Engine` set to `ON` in `Apache`

Comment: @StuartWagner: I have tried to add `RewriteBase /mylaravel/public/` But it still does not work. What is going on with Laravel 5.1...

Comment: @OConnor With the `RewriteBase`, you need to point to `index.php` in your `RewriteRule`, not `/index.php`.

Comment: @StuartWagner should it be RewriteRule . index.php [L] or RewriteRule ^  index.php [L] ?

Comment: @OConnor The second, like the Laravel default.

Comment: with all attempts, it only works when I access via http://localhost/mylaravel/public/index.php/test but with all of this configuration it should remove index.php from the url.

Comment: I have solved this issued as I have added <Directory "/var/www/html"> AllowOverride All </Directory> to /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf and restart the apache server. Now I can access the website without index.php in the URL. Thanks you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

With some help from the guys comments here I have solved this issue as I did the following. In the command line.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite

sudo service apache2 restart

sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Find `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` and add the following lines directly below:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

And restart the apache with the following command.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Use the default `.htaccess` provided by Laravel installation and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your local server running.
start your server by running this command in console:

```
php artisan serve --host=localhost --port=8080
```

and then try to access your app via this address:

```
http://localhost:8080/test
```

In laravel app, all requests are received by **index.php** file in your public directory and when you request sth like
http://localhost/mylaravel/public/test
then server thinks that you are requesting static files.